# Migration to Swift 2 "Use of unresolved identifier '***'"

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm upgrading my project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.

I use this occasion to upgrade lot of the lib that I use, in particular Alamofire.

But now I got this error on many of my request:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'notifTypeJSON'

Here is the code of one of the func:

```
func getNotifications(failure failure: (NSError) -> (), success: ([Notification]) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.Notifications)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                failure(error)
            } else {
                var json = JSON(response.data!)
                let status = json["error"].intValue
                if status != 0 {
                    failure(self.createError(status))
                } else {
                    var notifications = [Notification]()
                    let notificationsList = json["notification"]
                    for (index: String, notifTypeJSON: JSON) in notificationsList {
                        if let notifJSON = notifTypeJSON[NotificationTypes.Generic.rawValue].dictionaryObject {
                            notifications.append(GenericNotification(json: notifJSON))
                        }
                        else if let notifJSON = notifTypeJSON[NotificationTypes.Follow.rawValue].dictionaryObject {
                            notifications.append(FollowNotification(json: notifJSON))
                        }
                        else if let notifJSON = notifTypeJSON[NotificationTypes.Comment.rawValue].dictionaryObject {
                            notifications.append(CommentNotification(json: notifJSON))
                        }
                        else if let notifJSON = notifTypeJSON[NotificationTypes.Like.rawValue].dictionaryObject {
                            notifications.append(LikeNotification(json: notifJSON))
                        }
                    }
                    DDLogInfo("SeetyAPI getNotifications() success")
                    success(notifications)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 2 the way we loop over a dictionary with a tuple has changed: the types have to be in a separate tuple.

Example Before:

```
for (key:String, value:Int) in xxx {
```

Example After:

```
for (key, value):(String, Int) in xxx {
```

So for you, you would need to replace this:

```
for (index: String, notifTypeJSON: JSON) in notificationsList {
```

With this:

```
for (index, notifTypeJSON):(String, JSON) in notificationsList {
```